# Declare Constant at Runtime

Tags: java

I am reading from a file and setting values based on what I read from the file.

My question is:  If I wanted to declare one of the retrieved values from the file as a constant how would i do that?

Edit: Say that value is an "int" for simplicity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't suppose you're looking for the [`final`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) keyword?

```
final int foo = /* get it from the file */;
```

Comment: Yes but whenever I try to declare it as such: public static final int CONSTANT;   I cannot declare it as blank.                                        So basically I want to have this "public static final int Constant_Int;" in another class and use it later.

Comment: @Jonathan: that's right. You must initialize `static final` fields when you declare them, or in a [static initializer block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html). The second option may be the solution to this problem.

Comment: ahh okay i see static initializer block was my answer! thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what scope you want for this variable. The "final" keyword is about all you have to work with, as far as creating constants. It's easy enough to define a final local or instance variable in terms of runtime data, but declaring a static final class member is harder; you have to have the value available right when the class is loaded and initialized, so you have to do it somehow in a static initializer block:

```
public static final int CONSTANT;
static {
    CONSTANT = <something!>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way you could do it, just replace the generatePseudoConstant() with your function to read from the file system.

```
    public class PseudoConstant {

    public static final int PSEUDO_CONSTANT;
    private static final Random randomGen = new Random();

    static {
         PSEUDO_CONSTANT = generatePsudoConstant();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PseudoConstant instance1 = new PseudoConstant();
        PseudoConstant instance2 = new PseudoConstant();

        System.out.println("PSEUDO_CONSTANT (instance1) = " + instance1.PSEUDO_CONSTANT);
        System.out.println("PSEUDO_CONSTANT (instance2) = " + instance2.PSEUDO_CONSTANT);
    }

    private static int generatePsudoConstant() {
        return randomGen.nextInt(10);
    }
}
```

Cheers!